# How do I pass variables along the actions within the same controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Let this be the case.

- /Controller/ActionA/1  (showlist of items(has id - user id))
- /Controller/ActionB/2 (select item (id of item))
- /Controller/ActionC/3 (update item, needs use id as well as item id)

When I go from ActionA to ActionB and then ActionC, can I retrieve URL parameter of ActionA, in this case '1', when I reach Actionc ? and vice versa ?

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: actionA ->showlist of items(has id - user id)
actionB ->select item -> (id of item)
actionC -> update item, needs use id as well as item id

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide all the the previous parameters in the URLs that you create for going to other actions. Since the web is stateless, each request must contain all of the information you'll need to accomplish that request.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action B", "ActionB", 
    new{id=listItem.actionBId, actionAId = Model.Id});
```

And then:

```
public ActionResult ActionB(int id, int actionAId)
{
    ...
}
```

The only way you could avoid this is if the item that ActionB works on is somehow related to ActionA's item, in which case you'd want to infer that information from the server side:

```
public ActionResult ActionB(int id)
{
    int actionAId = GetActionAItemByB(id).Id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will try and ask if i need further assistance, thank you ! :) :)

Comment: I am thinking about using cookies to solve the problem, What do you think about that ... ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire: Bear in mind that cookies are shared across all browser windows, so you could end up with unexpected user experiences when someone is using your site from multiple tabs, or if they click the "Back" and "Forward" button.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're going from one action to another.  A standard approach is the `RedirectToAction()` method, which [has an overload to include route values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291.aspx):

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionB", new { id = x, someOtherRouteValue = y });
```

Comment: this should work i guess, so you mean i just add ids as i move along actions, right ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire: Well, that's the approach when you're using redirects to go from one action to another.  Which, again, is a standard approach.  But there may be a terminology mix-up here.  It sounds like you might be "going from one action to another" by means of invoking a new action from a rendered view?  That's not really going from one to another, that's just invoking an action from the UI.